# Terraform, how to capture an external environment variable?

Tags: terraform

I want to store an external environment variable from a compute instance during setup and use it in Terraform local var. This is what I have tried:

```
resource "null_resource" "get_env_token" {
  count = var.config_server_count

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    connection {
      type        = "ssh"
      user        = "opc"
      host        = "xxx"
      private_key = file(var.ssh_private_key)
    }

    inline = [
      "echo $WORKER_TOKEN"
    ]
  }

}
```

In locals:

```
locals {

  token = null_resource.get_env_token[0].provisioner.remote-exec.output

}
```

This will not work I get "This object has no argument, nested block, or exported attribute named
"provisioner". "

Is there a way to achieve this?

Comment: You could maybe echo the output to a file and then read the file in the local `token` variable.

Comment: I am unsure if `provisioner` is accessible in the attribute schema. I would speculate "no" given it is a meta-block.

Comment: @MarkoE Can you give me an example of how that could work

Comment: For example, `"echo $WORKER_TOKEN > ${path.root}/token.txt"` and then use the `file` built-in function read the token in, `token = file("${path.root}/token.txt")` but I am not sure that will work.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the `null_resource`, you could instead use the [SSH Provider](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/loafoe/ssh/latest/docs), which has a `ssh_resource` that allows running commands on a remote machine capturing the standard output in the `result` attribute:

```
resource "ssh_resource" "example" {
  host    = "xxx"
  user    = "xxx"
  port    = 22
  private_key = file(var.ssh_private_key)

  commands = [
     "echo $WORKER_TOKEN",
  ]
}
```

You can then reference the value of the env variable in your locals as follow:

```
locals {
  token = ssh_resource.example.result
}
```